# Query only geometry with ArcGIS REST service in Python

Tags: python, geojson

I'd like to query the geometry from a Mapserver: https://map.dfg.ca.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Project_BIOS_Public

The ulimtate goal is to query all the geometry for each layer and perform an intersect against a reference shapefile. I want to determine which layers intersect with a given watershed.

This is my first time working with the ArcGIS REST service. I'm a little confused on how I can extract only the geometry and the layer name... for the purposes of this exercise I just want a list of which layers intersect with a watershed I have as a shapefile.

I've written the following code (just specific URL for example)

```py
import requests
import json
import urllib
from collections import defaultdict

queryURL = 'https://map.dfg.ca.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Project_BIOS_Public/q_BIOS_Public_pointslines00/MapServer/0/query'
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'f': 'geojson', 'geometry':'Envelope', 'returnGeometry': 'true', 'OutFields':'*'}).encode("utf-8")


#requests query
req = urllib.request.Request(queryURL,params)

#opens the response
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

#loads response as json
jsonResult = json.load(response)

jsonResult
```

This returns the geometry but also all of the fields, and not the layer name. How do I get just the geometry and the layer name?

Comment: You've got multiple questions embedded in this question. If the REST endpoint doesn't accept a fields/columns list parameter, then the query will return all fields. I doubt you could ever make it return layer name, unless that's one of the fields. Returning geometry from rasters is unlikely, though extracting the envelope, from which 5-point polygons can be extracted should be simple enough.

Comment: You will need to convert your shapefile to geojson to send that query - there is only 708 features in that rest end point - Vince is correct envelope the query will be the quickest way.

Comment: Sorry for having more than one question in here. I can send the geometry of the shapefile to the rest service query to determine if they intersect? I see that now. Regarding the rasters, I need to extract that as an envelope? I'm having trouble constructing the url :https://map.dfg.ca.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Project_BIOS_Public/q_BIOS_Public_rasters06/MapServer/0

Comment: I've edited out the *too broad* raster query question; you can ask that after you do some more research.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite the same, but the JS API interface [documentation on outFields](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/query-amd.html#outfields) indicates that the REST API `OutFields` parameter is a column list.  You've provided:

```py
params = urllib.parse.urlencode(
            {'f': 'geojson', 
             'geometry':'Envelope', 
             'returnGeometry': 'true', 
             'OutFields':'*'}
         ).encode("utf-8")
```

where instead you could have provided:

```py
params = urllib.parse.urlencode(
            {'f': 'geojson', 
             'geometry':'Envelope', 
             'returnGeometry': 'true', 
             'OutFields':'shape'} # <<--- Or whatever the geometry column name is
         ).encode("utf-8")
```

which would have limited the return result to geometry.

If the data source was a view which hard-coded the source name in the result,
as in:

```sql
CREATE VIEW mylayer_v AS 
    SELECT objectid,field1,...fieldN,'mylayer'::varchar(32) as layername 
    FROM   mylayer
```

then you could query the layer published off `mylayer_v` with

```py
params = urllib.parse.urlencode(
            {'f': 'geojson', 
             'geometry':'Envelope', 
             'returnGeometry': 'true', 
             'OutFields':['shape','layername']} #  (might be 'shape,layername' -- haven't checked)
         ).encode("utf-8")
```

It would probably be much easier to populate the layer source on the client side than to hard-code the source into the database (since it's rarely a 1:1 relationship). It would also reduce the I/O and database overhead to avoid this approach.